# react router - keep the query string on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, query-string, react-router-redux

I would like to create routes that support query string.
When i say support i mean, passing it to the next route some how.
For example:
given this route: `domain/home?lang=eng`
and when moving to route `domain/about` i want it to keep the Query String and display `domain/about?lang=eng`.
I was sure there's a built in functionality for this but after reading the docs and a lot of search on the net, i couldn't find an elegant solution.
I'm using `react-router@3.0.0` and `react-router-redux@4.0.7`

Answer (score 0):

For react-router 4.x, try

`const { history }
history.push('/about' + history.location.search)`

To access `this.props.history`, make sure you have wrapped the component with `withRouter` HOC

`import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
export default withRouter(component)`

refer https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2185

Answer (score -2):

You will have to "forward" query param on each page transition - bothering and you can easily forgot to...

Instead, I would do this.

- read stored/persisted `lang` preference. `localStorage` is good candidate here. Fallback to default language, when no preference is found
- share `lang` via context, so that each and every component can read this value.
- create some button (or whatever), which would modify this value

Since you are using `redux`, I would pull `redux-persist` to persist this preference across page reloads.

Comment: the main reason i would like to persist the query string is to support url sharing, i.e: you want to share with your friend a url or save it to favorites, i would need some basic data in the url to display the initial store you had previously. it seems very strange that there isn't a built-in way in react-router for this, as if i'm not mistaken, react-router is the component that override's the url on each route change. i would think it can pass on the query params (at least by a flag)

Comment: You can write wrapper around React Router's push/replace methods, which will always set lang param then. To be honest, that should not be RR's responsibility, since it's very unique edge case (not setting app lang is unique, but always forwarding param is unique)

Comment: I think it is RR's responsibility as it is the one that manipulate and changing the url. and if we want the changes to be centralized we should do it there. as for the question about is this an edge case or not,  i think that a website that support URL sharing (a simple copy paste by the user) or saving a shortcut, is a very basic feature. keep in mind that the `lang` param was just an example.

Comment: Exactly, `lang` is just example. Forwarding params all across your app truly is not RR's responsibility. Do browser support this? Of course not. Having any kind of app, build with any JS framework, or even rendered on server, you have no way to tell browser "hey pal, take this lang param and use it everywhere. Create custom link, read `param` from URL and append it when creating `href`. Do very same for wrappers around push/replace actions. Your edge case is yours, mines are mines. No chance of supporting everything in every lib, unfortunately.